# How to get the second active window in z order?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I am trying to create an MFC application(hidden application) for tracking usage of other applications.

I am using GetForgroundWindow() for getting the current active window but sometimes I get my own hidden application window.
How I can get the current active windows in z-order

Comment: Completely unclear, what you're asking. My gut feeling is, that you want to use [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx), to monitor window activation events and friends.

Comment: Adding interpunctuation and paragraphs would already help so much to make this question more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `GetWindow` passing `GW_HWNDNEXT`.